# Java choose layout

Tags: java, layout, height, width, distribution

I need following layout in Java:

[image: Layout]

However, I should find that no layout manager can simply handle this problem for me. I need this layout in a JFrame.

Is there any halfway easy way I could do this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks, all of you, I finally managed!

That's what I've done (as you have proposed)

- BorderLayout for the window
- leftPanel, GridLayout(1,1) /* to stretch */, add Component 1, WEST in window
- rightPanel, BorderLayout, CENTER in window
- rightTop (added to rightPanel as CENTER) Panel, add Component 2
- rightBottom (added to rightPanel as SOUTH) Panel, GridLayout(1,1) (also for stretching), add Component 3

Thanks you all, whose advice I have mixed ^^

Comment: You should have a look to MigLayout: http://www.miglayout.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you solved your problem with a mix of `JPanels` placed within a `BorderLayout` layout manager. If that works, that's fine.

For those who are curious about using a `GridBagLayout` as a solution, I present this class as an example. Simply copy-paste, compile, and run. Drag the corner of this little app's window to see the effects of resizing the window.

[image: Screenshot of example layout code]
[image]

```
// Example code showing the flexibility of GridBagLayout.

// Source code generated by WindowBuilder 1.0.0r37 in Eclipse (Indigo Release) on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

// © 2011 Basil Bourque.   http://www.GridsGoneWild.com/
// This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

// Each layout manager bundled in Java is quite different from the others. They all have strengths and weaknesses,
// each designed for different purposes and effects.

// GridBagLayout is the most powerful and flexible, but takes some patient practice to understand.
// Funny animated video commentary by a GridBagLayout programmer: http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/
// Hand-coding GridBagLayout is certainly tedious, and nearly impossible for complex forms. So I recommend the use of
// a visual GUI builder such as WindowBuilder in Eclipse, JFormDesigner from FormDev.com, or Matisse in NetBeans.

// Key ideas, "grow" & "fill":
// • In WindowBuilder's Design View, select a widget, then use the "Horizontal grow" and "Vertical grow" icons found in the upper right tool bar.
// • Use the widget's (label's, button's) "Constraints" > "fill" property in the property sheet of WindowBuilder.

// Further ideas:
// • To contain multiple widgets in each area, use JPanel objects where I have used single JLabel and JButton objects. 
//   Nesting JPanels inside JPanels (or in the JFrame's contentPane) is considered normal in Swing. Each JPanel has its own layout manager.
// • If need be, you can set the Minimum, Maximum, and/or Preferred size of a widget or JPanel.
// • If you want certain widgets or JPanels to get disproportionately more or less of the space gained or lost when a window is resized, 
//   use "weightx" and "weighty" properties.

// WindowBuilder Tips:
// • If it's your first time: Open the .java file, then click the "Design" button at bottom to see visual editor.
// • Click the "Show Advanced properties" icon at top of a widget's property sheet to see many hidden properties.

// package com.your.package.goes.here;  // Uncomment this line, and modify to suit your own package.

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GridBagLayout_Example extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel lblVariableXVariableY;
    private JButton btnVariableXFixedY;
    private JLabel lblFixedXVariableY;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            GridBagLayout_Example frame = new GridBagLayout_Example();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public GridBagLayout_Example() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(this.contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    this.contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    this.lblFixedXVariableY = new JLabel("Fixed x, Variable y");
    this.lblFixedXVariableY.setOpaque(true);
    this.lblFixedXVariableY.setBackground(new Color(233, 150, 122));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblFixedXVariableY = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblFixedXVariableY.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_lblFixedXVariableY.gridheight = 2;
    gbc_lblFixedXVariableY.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblFixedXVariableY.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblFixedXVariableY.gridy = 0;
    this.contentPane.add(this.lblFixedXVariableY, gbc_lblFixedXVariableY);

    this.lblVariableXVariableY = new JLabel("Variable x & y");
    this.lblVariableXVariableY.setBackground(new Color(147, 112, 219));
    this.lblVariableXVariableY.setOpaque(true);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblVariableXVariableY = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblVariableXVariableY.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_lblVariableXVariableY.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblVariableXVariableY.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblVariableXVariableY.gridy = 0;
    this.contentPane.add(this.lblVariableXVariableY, gbc_lblVariableXVariableY);

    this.btnVariableXFixedY = new JButton("Variable x, Fixed y");
    this.btnVariableXFixedY.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
        }
    });
    this.btnVariableXFixedY.setOpaque(true);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnVariableXFixedY = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnVariableXFixedY.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnVariableXFixedY.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnVariableXFixedY.gridy = 1;
    this.contentPane.add(this.btnVariableXFixedY, gbc_btnVariableXFixedY);
    }

}
```

Comment: Being a big fan of nested layouts, who rarely uses & never recommends GBL, I thought I'd give your code the 'crash test'.  Nice example!  A couple of slight tips.  Don't set the bounds.  Instead, pack it, get the size (set that size as the minimum size for 1.6+) then set the size to a multiple of the current 'smallest' size (e.g. twice as wide & 5 times as tall).  Use either `setLocationByPlatform(true)` (1.6+) or `setLocation(int,int)` to position the frame.  Note also that it is not usually necessary to extend components, and not in this case.  But for an SSCCE, most rules are negotiable. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the screenshot. I went to upload my own screenshot this day later, and was pleasantly surprised to find yours. Notice on my Mac screenshot, the buttom of the button lines up. I'm surprised because Apple's JButton implementations draws a few pixels beyond what we perceive as the edge, yet it is your Windows button that is offset not my Mac button. Why?

Comment: Again, thanks for the feedback. I did not know about "setLocationByPlatform". A couple reaction comments to follow.

Comment: (A) While not trying to be argumentative, I would say your suggestions about setting the bounds and positioning the JFrame are beyond the scope of this topic: How to manage 3 resizable areas of a window. And practically speaking, it is legitimate to set the bounds to a size the designer/programmer deems an ideal starting size. Lastly, I'm trying to minimize the code to keep the example on point and short -- for example in a real app I would add an EmptyBorder to the contentPane to keep widgets away from the window edges.

Comment: (B) I don't understand your point about extending components. I used plain JLabel and JButton objects. The only extension is of the JFrame for the overall example. That is how Eclipse WindowBuilder and other GUI builders work, by creating a class that subclasses the JFrame.

Comment: *"That is how Eclipse WindowBuilder and other GUI builders work, by creating a class that subclasses the JFrame."*  Bad, bad window builder!  Fair point on the 'want to keep it short' comments.  I'll leave my first comment as extra info. the reader might want to consider.  The 2nd is now gone.  :)

Answer (score 2):

A borderlayout with 2 panels, one WEST and one CENTER. On the CENTER panel a borderLayout with both Center and Nrth components might work.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't particularly simple but I think you have to use GridBagLayout. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: I did try GridBagLayout. Only thing is, it stretched the components very strangely. I could not tell it: this component needs a FIXED width, and the very same I am telling, while the other one needs to actually FILL both axes ^^

Comment: @arik Alternatively you could add two JPanels one for the left side and one for the right side. In the right JPanel it would contain two JPanels. Each aforementioned JPanel can have a different layout manager. It's been awhile since I did swing but I think that would work.

Comment: Thanks… that seems like a good approach. I will tell you whether it worked once I tried it out.

Comment: @arik if you post your GridBagLayout code I will look at it when I get home. It may be that you were very close to a correct implementation. By the way, is it required that the (height of component 2 + 3) = (height of component 1)?

Comment: Nope. It should only look roughly like it does on the image. What I need is that the width of component 1 and the height of component 3 stay the same no matter how I resize the window.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread one of the captions which led to my previous question. GridBagLayout would seem like the perfect fit for this task, but using different JPanels like I mentioned should also work. Again, if you can post the GridBag code I'll take a look, but if you can't that's understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the support and that idea with those panels. That's what I needed most.

Comment: Thanks for all your new approaches, each of which, I am sure, is great. Unfortunately, however, I can only use one of them. But thanks for the huge future reference!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to my previous answer is MigLayout.

It is an external dependency (it's not in the JDK) but it's one of the most powerfull layouts available. And with a GUI builder like [Google's WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) it's also very easy to use (or play with).

Even if you don't want to create your GUI with WindowBuilder it can sure help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with a simple BorderLayout with a JPanel WEST and one EAST.

My code

```
...
inGameFrame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
inGameFrame.getContentPane ().add ("East", pnlRight);
inGameFrame.getContentPane ().add ("South", pnlBottom);
inGameFrame.getContentPane ().add ("Center", pnlGameBoard);
...
```

If that does not work, try setting the panels' or components' size.
*(Even if I resize the JFrame, only the centered panel changes size)*

**EDIT**
What you can try is: add the panel west, and add a new panel center (also BorderLayout). Then on the new panel add your other two panels, one center and one bottom. That will get the desired effect.

```
...
JPanel pnlNew = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
pnlNew.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
pnlNew.add ("Center", pnlMiddle);
pnlNew.add ("South", pnlBottom);
frame.getContentPane ().add ("West", pnlLeft);
frame.getContentPane ().add ("Center", pnlNew);
...
```

Comment: It nearly does work, with that slight disadvantage that Component 3 is BELOW Component 1 (I changed "East" to "West"). Do you know a solution where pnlRight, in your case, or Component 1, in mine, fill the WHOLE height of the window and have the other components align to the right (your case) or left (mine) of it?